# Inset plot over video on matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, activex, vlc

I have embedded VLC player in a figure in Matlab, I want to show a video with an inset plot. Right now I can show both plot and video in one figure side by side, but I want to overlay the plot on the video. When the positions of my figure and my video overlay, always the video appears in front of the plot so when the video uses the same space as the plot. Is it possible to make the plot, and maybe other components as buttons appear over the video or I should always show the video and plots in different spaces.

This is my code example: In figure 1 both the vlc and figures are shown side by side. On figure 2 and 3, both the vlc and plot intersect in a region. No mather if I insert the axes first or the actxcontrol, the video is shown over the plots. What should be done to get the plot overlaying the video?

```
fig1=figure(1)
set(fig1,'Units','pixels')
size=get(fig1,'Position')
sizeX=size(3);
sizeY=size(4);
A = imread('westconcordaerial.png');    
axesFramed = axes('Parent',fig1,'Units','pixels','Layer','top','Tag','axesFramed','Position',[sizeX/2 0 sizeX/2 sizeY])
axes(axesFramed)
image(A);
vlc=actxcontrol('VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2',[0 0 sizeX/2 sizeY],fig1);
fig2=figure(2)
set(fig2,'Units','pixels')
size=get(fig2,'Position')
sizeX=size(3);    
sizeY=size(4);
axesFramed =axes('Parent',fig2,'Units','pixels','Layer','top','Tag','axesFramed','Position',[0 sizeY/4 sizeX sizeY/2])
axes(axesFramed)
image(A);
vlc2=actxcontrol('VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2',[0 0 sizeX/2 sizeY],fig2);
fig3=figure(3)
set(fig3,'Units','pixels')
size=get(fig3,'Position')
sizeX=size(3);
sizeY=size(4);
vlc3=actxcontrol('VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2',[0 0 sizeX/2 sizeY],fig3);
axesFramed = axes('Parent',fig3,'Units','pixels','Layer','top','Tag','axesFramed','Position',[0 sizeY/4 sizeX sizeY/2])
axes(axesFramed)
image(A);
```